# Bumping up bottom element

Tags: css, xhtml

On this site: http://www.catonthecouchproductions.com/new/ - I have been trying to remove the space between the two red borders, for I can keep my latest projects box without scrolling. Right now it has a slight scroll, then if you click the blue box at the top in Latest Projects, it pulls up a Client List.

I am talking about the vertical scrolling. I set the borders for you can see what element is what and what space is occupies.

My goal is to have it push the other content up, but first to start with the scrolling.

The big gap between the main content box and the bottom box.

Any ideas on what I can do fix that?

My css is here: http://www.catonthecouchproductions.com/new/style.css

Answer (score 0):

First of all your site is looking great!

As for the red border causing a horizontal scroll bar, the only way to fix that is remove the border all together. It seems as if that blue box at the bottom stretches to 100% of the page width. Unfortunately when you ad a 1 pixel border it adds two pixels to the width of that 100% div so it ends up taking more than 100% of the window. To my knowing their is no way to fix this with CSS, so you have to get rid of the border all together.

Comment: Hey, I had the border for debugging. Sorry, i should have mentioned that. I should have stressed to the vertical scrolling.